# Update page content after jQuery UI Slider change

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'm using jquery Ui slider for a web-project, and i have a small problem, i must update page content after the value of slider is changed, i'm not familiar with ajax, so show me please an example of doing it, i think i must send a post request to server, with new data

my html code

```
<div>
<p class='stops_air'>Price</p>  
<input type="text" id="price_option_right" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
<div id="slider-range"></div><br />
<input type="button" value="More Filters" class="more_filters_right_option">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like that :

```
$('yoursliderselector').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'yoururl',
        data : {yourdata},
        success : function(data){
            // process to update here
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT :

for any kind of input

```
$('input').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'yoururl',
        data : $(this).val(),
        success : function(data){
            // process to update here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you want to update your data for every <input> change in your page ?

Comment: Then you should use less specific selector like $('myfields input') and then use $(this) to call for the field you selected

Comment: yes, look at this form and you'll understand what i mean, thanks

Comment: if you don't have a specific kind of input to observe, my edit should work

Answer (score 0):

example code...

```
$("#elementid").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        // write your jQuery post code here
        $.post("url", function(data){
           // write your page update code here
        });
    }
});
```